# UWP Get unique id from user logged microsoft store account

Tags: c#, uwp, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I need unique id to save user purchases to my database. i dont need device id because if user change microsoft store account then device id will be same to previus.

I want to a leaderboard to most users purchases but i dont know him id if user change own device .

Comment: Have you tried to use receipts? [Requesting a receipt](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/use-receipts-to-verify-product-purchases#requesting-a-receipt)

Comment: i dont see any unique id for user @MKH

Comment: You can get and save unique transactions id from receipts then save it to your database for each username or userid who logged in to your app. Then you can calculate user purchases count locally or online.

Comment: @mkh App have no login or user id.

Answer (score 0):

The best you could do would be to have their app call `StoreContext.GetUserCollectionsAsync` from the UWP app on the user machine, then forward these results to your services.  This isn’t really all the purchase, but is all the things the user currently owns.

Or, using your UWP app again, just keep track of it immediately after the purchase succeeded.  But I don’t think there is any way to look up their purchase history directly.

A more complicated solution would be to use the [B2B](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.services.store.storecontext.getcustomercollectionsidasync) APIs. This would allow them to query the collections service directly from their service. This is probably the closest to what you are wanting. The token that get back would be unique to the user (not device).

Comment: yes,  Azure Active Directory  is complex. :(. I  need just a unique id for user. i dont understand this is no way

Comment: Will that work for developer-managed consumables?  Will they remain in GetUserCollectionsAsync as long as the user's store account exists?